# How to plot complex number

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to plot a point in the complex number plane like that:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import*
i = complex(3,1)*2
plot(i,'b.')
show()`
```

However the resulting plot displays the point `z=3+0i`. How can I make it take the imaginary component into account?

Answer (score 3):

Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part.

Please try this

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i = complex(3,1)*2
plt.plot(i.real, i.imag,'b.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the real and imaginary parts of your object `i`:

```
plot(i.real,i.imag,'b.')
```

**Edit:**

To adress the question you are asking in the comments, you just supply the list of real parts and imaginary parts independently, and you also have to remove the "." from the "b." part, *e.g.*

```
# a and b are instances of complex
plt.plot([a.real, b.real], [a.imag, b.imag],"b")
```

Note that you can find this information using the `help()` function on those functions.

Comment: By the way, do you know how can i link two of my complex number points?

Comment: That's just because I imported pyplot with `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` , in your case removing the `plt.` part should do the job